# Best approach to periodically check MongoDB from Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a MongoDB database with events coming in from other servers and I also have a Node.js server that I am planning to use at the back-end as a decision engine. What is the recommended approach in order to check specific tables full of events and in order to make certain decisions? I want to ensure that my Node.js can scale and that it can check periodically (user defined interval) the MongoDB server for new events. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. I am using express for my node server.

Comment: How are you transferring the data from the server to the client. Is it a websocket or api calls?

Comment: I don't want to serve any content to the client. I just want to use this as a service that checks the data and makes decisions

Comment: How much data-crunching is involved each time it makes the decision? Is it making the decision once per user? What factors make the decision change?

Comment: Initially I am building this for proof of concept purposes. There will be a few joins and I will need to use the aggregation pipeline. So probably a few things but if I do the polling every few seconds there shouldn't be too many events to check.

Comment: I see two good options: 1. observe mongo's operation log for events that are relevant to your aggregation and trigger the computation as necessary (you could even trigger the process once every X events occur). 2. Polling regularly, in which case I would base how often it runs on how long it takes to complete.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to experiment.